# How to print the contents of the JQuery ThickBox plugin?

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I have implemented the ThickBox Plugin and I am retrieving the content from using an AJAX request.  The print link is printing the page behind the Thickbox.  Is there a way to print the actual content?

I am using the following anchor tag and JavaScript link:

```
<a onclick="PrintPage()">Print</a>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
    function PrintPage() {
        window.print();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to specify a CSS print stylesheet which hides everything except the ajax retrieved content.